# Image Classification Using Google Cloud Vision API

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I have a Flask app in which a user uploads a file and then I make a request to google cloud vision API to classify it.

I'm doing the following:

```py
@app.route('/cloud_vision', methods=['POST'])
def cloud_vision():
    files = flask.request.files.getlist('files')

    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    if len(files) > 1 or files[0].filename != '':
        for file in files:
            with io.open(file, 'rb') as image_file:
                content = image_file.read()
            image = vision.Image(content=content)
            response = client.label_detection(image=image)
            labels = response.label_annotations
            (...)
```

But im getting this error `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage` when opening the file. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

**Please note that I'm not familiar with flask** but to resolve your issue you should use `file.filename` in `io.open()`. I used the sample code in this [article](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/handling-file-uploads-with-flask) to be able to use `getlist()`. See code below:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from google.cloud import vision
import io

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    files = request.files.getlist('file')

    if len(files) > 1 or files[0].filename != '':
        for file in files:
            file.save(file.filename) # I add saving for testing

            with io.open(file.filename, 'rb') as image_file: # use file.filename
                content = image_file.read() 

            image = vision.Image(content=content)
            response = client.label_detection(image=image)
            labels = response.label_annotations

    return str(labels)

if __name__==('__main__'):
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>File Upload</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>File Upload</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <p><input type="file" name="file"></p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Testing (image used is seen [here](https://github.com/googleapis/python-vision/blob/e30a0aec4bd52cbdd17fa3cca67d969581983ba4/samples/snippets/quickstart/resources/wakeupcat.jpg)):

[image]

After submitting the image, I returned the response on the webpage.

Output after submitting the image:

[image]